# MySQL: LEFT JOIN TWO tables with preference for specific rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Offshoot of this question: [MySQL: LEFT JOIN table with preference for specific rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70991417/mysql-left-join-table-with-preference-for-specific-rows)

I have a Contacts table, a PhoneNumbers table, and a ContactPhoneNumber table. Additionally, I have a ContactAddress and Address tables. A Contact can haveMany PhoneNumbers via the ContactPhoneNumber pivot table and can also haveMany Address via the ContactAddress table. Both a PhoneNumber and an Address can be marked as primary or not. A contact can also have no primary phone number or address or in fact no phone number or address at all.

My issue is that I need to retrieve all contacts, whether they have a phone number / address or not. Additionally, for each contact, I need to retrieve their PRIMARY phone number and address if they have one. If not, retrieve a non primary phone number / address or lastly, return no phone number / address. Joining the tables is not an issue, but I'm having trouble coming up with a way to prefer the primary phone number / address over the non primary phone number / address . Because, if I add a `WHERE isPrimary = 1` to the query, it's going to now eliminate those users who don't have a primary phone number. Instead, I simply need to prefer the 1, but also be OK with a 0 if no 1 exists. My query so far is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM Contact
LEFT JOIN ContactPhoneNumber ON ContactPhoneNumber.ContactID = Contact.ContactID
LEFT JOIN PhoneNumber ON ContactPhoneNumber.PhoneNumberID = PhoneNumber.PhoneNumberID
LEFT JOIN ContactAddress ON ContactAddress.ContactID = Contact.ContactID
LEFT JOIN Address ON ContactAddress.AddressID = Address.AddressID
GROUP BY Contact.ContactID;
```

The SQL Fiddle of this problem can be found at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c24a5/4

Comment: A side note on db design. When two persons share the same address and the address is primary for one of them ant is not primary for the other,  the  `Address` must contain two rows for the same address. Shoudn't  `isPrimary` be a column in `ContactAddress` instead? Same with `PhoneNumber`.

Comment: Yes, 100%. This is a legacy database and we need to move the content over to the new system. The design choices here don't make much sense, but this was done by the previous software vendor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left join with the filtered by priority phones and addresses.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Contact c
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT cn.ContactID, n.PhoneNumber,
    row_number() over(partition by cn.ContactID order by n.IsPrimary desc) as rn
  FROM ContactPhoneNumber cn 
  LEFT JOIN PhoneNumber n ON cn.PhoneNumberID = n.PhoneNumberID
) ph ON ph.ContactID = c.ContactID AND ph.rn = 1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT cn.ContactID, n.Address,
    row_number() over(partition by cn.ContactID order by n.IsPrimary desc) as rn
  FROM ContactAddress cn 
  LEFT JOIN Address n ON cn.ContactAddressID = n.ContactAddressID
) a ON a.ContactID = c.ContactID AND a.rn = 1
```

Comment: This seems logical, but I can't get it to work. Running your query results in You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by cn.ContactID order by n.IsPrimary desc) as rn FROM ContactPhoneN' at line 5

Comment: That means your MySQL version doesn't support windows function. You can run `SELECT version();` to check. If it's not MySQL v8+ and above, then this query can't run.

Comment: @Kevin,  how is the answer using the same row_number() is accepted on your previous question? That make me think you are on a modern MySql version.

Comment: You're right. I was testing in SQL Fiddle, which only has 5.6. On our actual database server it works fine. Thank you for your help!